# NumHiddenUnits in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

When we create an `LSTM` layer in matlab then we specify `numHiddenUnits` as `layer = lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)`. I have two questions about it.

(1) : What is mean by `numHiddenUnits`?

Does it represent the number of `LSTM` cells? If yes then are these cells connected serially or parallel(having no interaction between them).

Unfortunately, there is no way to visualize the (RNN)network. I understand how one LSTM cell works but i have no idea how the following architecture looks like.

My networks is made up of these layers.

```
`layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(numFeatures)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)
    fullyConnectedLayer(numResponses)
    regressionLayer];`
```

(2): How does this architecture looks like?

My approach: I tried to sketch it and i think it should look like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Your first question seems to be related to Matlab, i.e. it's a programming issue. If that's the case, this question is off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I might migrate this post to Stack Overflow. However, note that there's also Data Science SE that is more appropriate for these questions. If nobody provides an answer SO, ask it on DS SE.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the significance of numHiddenUnits:

LSTM is generally used where we deal with the sequences. Suppose that, you provide one english sentence as input to your LSTM network. Here input will be passed to the network word by word, not entire sentence at the same time.

Suppose that at time t0 word "stack" is the input of the network. Word "stack" will be decoded into some 1-D vector form before feeding into the network. Let suppose that vector size is 10 so, number of hidden units will be 10. In nutshell number of hidden units is equal to the vector dimension.